# How can I create my own meta transaction relayer?

Tags: solidity, meta-transactions, account-abstraction

I wish to create my own meta transaction relayer.

I already know how to have users sign transaction data and have the signature send to a third-party relayer like OpenZeppelin Defender or Biconomy.

The problem with these relayers is that they don't support all the EVM chains that I am building on. My solution is creating my own relayer. I've tried having AIs like ChatGPT and Bard explain to me how to do so but they've failed in the process.

So, how can I create my own relayer which executes transactions on behalf of the signer when given a valid signature?

This is how my logic should flow in my react/next.js dapp:

1. User presses button and is prompted to sign a transaction (say, transfer 0.000000001 eth to the 0 address)
2. User signs transaction
3. Upon receiving the awaited signature, the dapp sends the transaction with its own wallet to a relayer containing the user's transaction signature.

The relayer completes whatever process it needs, and in the end the transaction is submitted to the network as if the user executed the transaction themselves. In this case, 0.000000001 eth is transferred to the 0 address from the user.

How would you create this relayer?

Also, will this require nothing but smart contracts or something else?